# Search box icon keeps disapearing

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

In Windows 10 Enterprise v. 1709, 16288.371 the search icon keeps disapearing form the task bar. 
I have even set the registry key:

```
Počítač\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search
```

to value 1.

After every login the search icon disappears, it might be some GPO or login script in place since the PC is part of an enterprise domain.

What can be the cause of this behavior (which policy etc.) and is there a way how to override it without restarting explorer.exe or selecting to show the task icon from the  context menu? I mean some simple script etc., something that would work without me clicking it all the time.

---

I thought that the registry value remained 1 but it was changed to 0 after the logoff, so setting it to 1 may fix the problem, but will I have to restart explorer.exe..?

So the question is

1) Which group policy can change the registry value on logoff to 0.

2) What is the workaround script that fights that "wrong" GPO policy back?

(Recently I have observed also that the icon goes away even without logoff)

Comment: Collect the domain group policy via gpresult /h to see if it's group policy caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very basic workaround. The same functionality of search icon can be achieved by pinning the search icon found in start menu to the task bar and moving it to the left. It does the same thing and it is independent from applied goup policies, scripts or registry settings. This works with latest creators update.

The reason for this behavior are domain logon scripts, probably directly setting some registry values.

Answer (score 2):

In general, under the following path, all search related GPOs should be configured as Not Configured, check it at first.

Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Search

Then, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search

0 = Hidden

1 = Show search or Cortana icon

2 = Show search box

You have set it as 1, that’s ok.

I suspect that your user profile exists trouble, try to backup your personal data and delete current user profile, login again for test.

Comment: It is a problem of all the user profiles in the domain, sorry I have not mentioned that.

Comment: Checked rsop.msc and do not see any settings in GPO you have mentioned, perhaps it is something in Users specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your **SearchboxTaskbarMode** registry value to 2. Since

0 = Hidden

1 = Show Cortana icon

2 = Show search box

Comment: I would like to see magnify glass icon rather the search box, I wil give it a try...

Comment: If so, check if your searchboxtaskbarmode is always set to 0 during the login. if yes, it should be the group policy or login script. collect the group policy report to confirm it.